# The memory copy from text segment is not the same with the original

Tags: ios, memory, arm, instructions

In iOS, I copy memory use the code below:

```
memcpy(code, oriAddress  , 100);
```

where `oriAddress`  point  to  text segment(a funtion's address). My problem is ,the memory in `oriAddress` is not the same with  in code. How this happen?

[image]

[image]

Before the arm instruction ldrh execute, the value pointed by 0x2a305ad4 is  0xb5f0. But after ldrh execute,the value of r0 is not 0xb5f0.

Comment: How do you compare memory regions? Do you use `memcmp` for that?

Comment: No, I compare it in debug window use lldb

Comment: Are you debugging **user space** (application) code? If so, why `kernel` tag?

Comment: Yes,It's user space code ,sorry for that.  I misunderstood the word kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s my fault. I set a BreakPoint to the address,And lldb change the value pointed by the address. So the value is the BreakPoint code.